# Add an array in PHP into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to add a PHP array in a mysql table?

```
try {
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // Prepare the statement so that it gets repeated
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (taskdescription) VALUE ('$task')");

    //For each task in our list pass it into the query to be executed
    foreach ($list as $task) {
        $sql->execute($task);
    }

    echo "Tasks inserted into task table successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I would like to do this in [PDO<sup>PHP</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) so that it matches the rest of my code. At the moment it says it has inserted the tasks but when i check on phpmyadmin it appears empty...

Comment: Check for SQL errors.

Comment: Read about prepared statements

Comment: can you dump the $list for us?

Comment: list = (first, second, third);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use prepared statement, you can send "parameters".
For example your task (string type?), can be send as a parameter in the query :

```
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (taskdescription) VALUE (:task)");
```

And then when you execute the query :

```
$sql->execute(['task' => $task]);
```

Comment: Will this insert every single task in my array or just one?

Comment: If you use it in your foreach loop, then all will be inserted.

Comment: Thanks this worked, how can i add the same listid for every task?

Comment: Cool :)
You can update your prepared query : 
VALUE (:id, :task)
and then add a second parameter when executing :
$sql->execute(['task' => $task, 'id' => $id]);

Answer (score -1):

First of all i'll advice to use prepared statements and bind its params.
Try this:

```
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tasks (taskdescription) VALUE     (:taskdescription)");
 foreach ($list as $task) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam(':taskdescription', $task);
        $stmt->execute($task);
    }
```

Comment: this is not how prepared queries are supposed to be run